# pre_gen_project hook script didn't exit successfully

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash, react-boilerplate, cookiecutter-django, cookiecutter

Generating a dash component project using cookiecutter.

Followed the installation guide of dash-component-boilerplate: https://github.com/plotly/dash-component-boilerplate

Ubuntu 18.04.5 (WSL)
Node - v8.10.0
NPM - 3.5.2
python - 3.6.9
pip - 9.0.1
cookiecutter - 1.7.3
virtualenv - 20.16.7

Steps

1. Install Node.js and NPM
2. pip install cookiecutter
3. Answered the questions about the project (as given in the installation README.md)

Error Message
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDamx.png)

Answer (score 0):

[re.Pattern.fullmatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=fullmatch#re.Pattern.fullmatch) is added in Python 3.4. To get this run properly, you should install your cookiecutter with Python 3.4 or greater.

You could see what Python version is cookiecutter using by executing `cookiecutter --version`.

If your system Python3 is greater than 3.4 (and it most probably is), you could uninstall cookiecutter and than install it with:
`python3 -m pip install --user cookiecutter`

Keep in mind, that you may have other problems, related to the template. If you get different error, after you run this with the correct Python version, you could take a look at the issues section of the project:
https://github.com/plotly/dash-component-boilerplate/issues/148#issuecomment-1342915082